# How to show Woo Category (clothing) and WP Category (php) at a time in wordpress php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to show only two categories one from wp categories (category name - php) and one from woo categories (category name - clothing) and hide remaining woo and wp categories except php and clothing. How can i do this?

```
function custom_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {
  $tax_query = (array) $q->get( 'tax_query' );

  $tax_query[] = array(
       'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
       'field' => 'slug',
       'terms' => array( 'clothing' ), // clothing is woo category name
       'operator' => 'IN'
  );

  $tax_query[] = array(
       'taxonomy' => 'category',
       'field' => 'slug',
       'terms' => array( 'php' ), // php is wp category name
       'operator' => 'IN'
  );

  $q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );
```

Comment: there's no question or problem statement here. What issue are you facing? What have you tried? What results are you getting? Precisely what results are you expecting? Just an unexplained code dump and a vague title does not constitute a question.

Comment: How to show Woo Category (clothing) and WP Category (php) at a time in wordpress php                                                                                                     I want to display two categories one from wp categories and one from woo categories and hide remaining woo and wp categories. That's my question.

Comment: The question should be within the text for clarity, not just the title. But it's not clear enough anyway. Again: "What issue are you facing? What have you tried? What results are you getting? Precisely what results are you expecting?". Just asking "how can I..." tells us nothing about your situation. How is the code above relevant, for instance? Is it just your existing code, and you haven't tried to solve the problem yet? (In which case, you should research and try first, if you can). Or is it your attempt to do it? In that case, what is going wrong? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I want to show only two categories one from wp categories (category name - php) and one from woo categories (category name - clothing) and hide remaining woo and wp categories using specified action mentioned clearly. how can you do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the solution guys...

```
           `$tax_query[] = array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                    'field' => 'term_id',
                    'terms' => array('php'),
                    'operator' => 'IN'
                ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'field' => 'term_id',
                    'terms' => array('clothing'),
                    'operator' => 'IN'
                )
            );`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array(
'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => array('clothing'),
        'operator' => 'IN'
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => array('php'),
        'operator' => 'IN'
    )
  )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Already tried that one but i got a fatal error mentioned below. When am using like this $query = new WP_Query( $args );                              Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting! in D:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\cache.php on line 541